# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have to make a Sudoku game. When I tried code it I found a problem, which I can't repair on my own. I'm using SceneBuilder.If you have any ideas to resolve my problem or some advices I would be really thankful
That's my code:
FXMLDocumentController

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private GridPane grid;
public TextField[][] field= new TextField[9][9];
public class getXY{
    private TextField temp;
    private int a;
    int x,y;
    public int getNodeByRowColumnIndex(final int row,final int column,GridPane gridPane) {
    Node result = null;
    ObservableList<Node> childrens = gridPane.getChildren();
    for(Node node : childrens) {
        if(gridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row && gridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == column) {
            temp = (TextField) node;
            a=Integer.parseInt(temp.getText());
            break;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
}
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    getXY a = new getXY();
    for (int i=0; i<9;i++)
        for (int j=0; j<9;j++){

    //int temp=a.getNodeByRowColumnIndex(i, j, grid);
    System.out.println("1");

        }

        }




@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    for (int i=0; i<9;i++)
        for (int j=0; j<9;j++){
            //field[i][j].setText("0");
            TextField ffield = new TextField("0");
            grid.add(ffield,i,j);
        }      
}  }
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="411.0" prefWidth="639.0"        xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sudokuv2.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
<GridPane fx:id="grid" gridLinesVisible="true" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="51.0" onKeyReleased="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="338.0" prefWidth="596.0">
<columnConstraints>
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
  </GridPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And result is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include the complete stack trace

Answer (score 6):

Your handler method is linked to the `onKeyReleased` handler for the `GridPane`:

```xml
<GridPane fx:id="grid" ... onKeyReleased="#handleButtonAction" ... >
```

Since [`onKeyReleased`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyReleasedProperty) expects an `EventHandler<KeyEvent>`, your method (which you very confusingly named `handleButtonAction`) parameter type should be `KeyEvent`, not `ActionEvent`:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(KeyEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```